# Difference from one collection from another collection using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have two collections. First one is of complex type that contains two string properties

chpt_cd and appl_src_cd

```
public class ChapterCodeValidationOutput
{
    public string chpt_cd { get; set; }
    public string appl_src_cd { get; set; }
}
```

And it's get stored in a variable _validChapterCodeLst.

It's sample data may look like :

```
chpt_cd    aapl_src_cd
-------    -----------

07038      C062
06206      C191
```

The input to the method that produces the collection is a collection of strings.

```
List<string> _chapterCodes
```

that may contain data like :

```
'070038'
```

I want to find the difference between the two collection and put them in two separate lists accordingly.

Whichever is there in the **_validChapterCodeLst** should be the Valid Output List and it should have two columns likewise

**chpt_cd and associated appl_src_cd**
and the invalid list should contain the difference between **_validChapterCodeLst** and **_chapterCodes** input list. And also should contain two columns likewise.

I tried

```
gmvo._invalidChapterCodes = gmvi._chapterCodes.Except(_validChapterCodeLst.ConvertAll(x => x.chpt_cd.ToString())).ToList();
```

I tried to convert _validChapterCodeLst to List first and then perform Except.

But that did not work .

Also I do not know how to get the associated appl_src_cd .

Output should be

06206 C191

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Except` accepts only collections of the same type. However, you can try this (I used `HashSet` here for better performance):

```
var _chapterCodesHashSet = new HashSet<string>(_chapterCodes);
var _invalidChapterCodes = _validChapterCodeLst.Where(item => !_chapterCodesHashSet.Contains(item.chpt_cd)).ToList();
```

Comment: For O(1) search Hashset is always much better than simple List, O(n), good code

Comment: @stop-cran Ok but new HashSet<string>(_validChapterCodeLst) is throwing exception , how are you supposed to cast a collection of complex object type to collection of string ?

Comment: @StrugglingCoder, correct. Edited names in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I used where

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<ChapterCodeValidationOutput> _validChapterCodeLst = new List<ChapterCodeValidationOutput>() {
                new ChapterCodeValidationOutput() { chpt_cd =  "07038", appl_src_cd = "C062"},
                new ChapterCodeValidationOutput() { chpt_cd =  "06206", appl_src_cd = "C191"}
            };
            List<string> _chapterCodes = new List<string>() { "07038" };
            var results = _validChapterCodeLst.Where(x => !_chapterCodes.Contains(x.chpt_cd)).Select(y => new { chpt_cd = y.chpt_cd, appl_src_cd = y.appl_src_cd}).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class ChapterCodeValidationOutput
    {
        public string chpt_cd { get; set; }
        public string appl_src_cd { get; set; }
    }
}
```